# Hard-code each value/property from API JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm practicing javascript and have some trouble hard-coding two of the properties from the JSON I'm using: `strMeasure` and `strIngredient`. I want to remove each `strMeasure` and `strIngredient` property  that has null value, but I can't figure out how to do it or fail while trying. What am I doing wrong or missing? What do I need to do to achieve this? I don't need answers for how to do it for every single property from inside its API JSON, but an example for one or two would be nice to get better understanding of this (e.g. `strMeasure7` and `strIngredient7` and so on).

Here's the codes I'm working on and got so far:

```js
const url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita";
const list = document.querySelector(".results");

async function getMargaritas() {

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();

        for (let i = 0; i < data.drinks.length; i++) {

            list.innerHTML += `<div class="result">
            <h1> ${data.drinks[i].strDrink} </h1>
            <ul>
            <li> ${data.drinks[i].strMeasure1} ${data.drinks[i].strIngredient1}</li>
            <li> ${data.drinks[i].strMeasure2} ${data.drinks[i].strIngredient2}</li>
            <li> ${data.drinks[i].strMeasure3} ${data.drinks[i].strIngredient3}</li>
            <li> ${data.drinks[i].strMeasure4} ${data.drinks[i].strIngredient4}</li>
            <li> ${data.drinks[i].strMeasure5} ${data.drinks[i].strIngredient5}</li>
            <li> ${data.drinks[i].strMeasure6} ${data.drinks[i].strIngredient6}</li>
            <li> ${data.drinks[i].strMeasure7} ${data.drinks[i].strIngredient7}</li>
            </ul>
            </div>`;

        }


    } catch (error) {
        list.innerHTML = theError("Whoops, sorry! No drink for you this time.. Better luck next time &#128521;");

    } 
}

getMargaritas();

function theError(message = "Error") {
   return `<div class="error">${message}</div>`;
}
```

```html
<div class="results"></div>
```

Let me know if something is unclear or if I need to elaborate further here

Comment: What makes you think you need to _remove_ anything from your JS object (_not_ JSON, JSON is a string, once you call `res.json()`, you turn that string into a real JS object) rather than simply testing for whether your property exists before you try to use it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url =
  "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita";
const list = document.querySelector(".results");

async function getMargaritas() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    for (let i = 0; i < data.drinks.length; i++) {
      list.innerHTML += `<div class="result">
            <h1> ${data.drinks[i].strDrink} </h1>
            <ul>`;
      let index = 1;
      while (data.drinks[i]["strIngredient" + index]) {
        let measure = data.drinks[i]["strMeasure" + index];
        let ingredient = data.drinks[i]["strIngredient" + index];
        let liString = measure ? measure + " " + ingredient : ingredient;
        list.innerHTML += `<li> ${liString}</li>`;
        index++;
      }
      list.innerHTML += `</ul>
            </div>`;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    list.innerHTML = theError(
      "Whoops, sorry! No drink for you this time.. Better luck next time &#128521;"
    );
  }
}

getMargaritas();

function theError(message = "Error") {
  return `<div class="error">${message}</div>`;
}
```

```html
<div class="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing Id do is turn that slightly bonkers response into something more meaningful, where you can also filter out the null ingredients:

```
function makeNonBonkersResult(data){
    const fields = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    return data.drinks.map(d => {
      return {
         name: d.strDrink,
         ingredients: fields.filter(f => d["strIngredient" + f] != null)
                            .map(f => ({ingredient: d["strIngredient" + f], measure: d["strMeasure" + f]}))
      }
    })
}
```

This turns the response you get from the api to something a bit easier to work with

```
[
  {
    name:"Margarita",
    ingredients: [ {ingredient: "Tequila", measure: "1 1/2 Oz"}, {ingredient:"...", measure: "..."} ]
  }
]
```

Then it becomes much easier to render, as you just loop over the `ingredients` array. As below demonstrates:

```js
const url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita";
const list = document.querySelector(".results");

async function getMargaritas() {

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = makeNonBonkersResult(await response.json());

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const drink = data[i];
            list.innerHTML += `<div class="result">
            <h1> ${drink.name} </h1>
            <ul>`
            for(let j=0;j<drink.ingredients.length;j++){
              list.innerHTML += `<li>${drink.ingredients[j].measure || ""} ${drink.ingredients[j].ingredient}</li>`
            }
            
            list.innerHTML += `</ul>
            </div>`;

        }


    } catch (error) {
        list.innerHTML = theError("Whoops, sorry! No drink for you this time.. Better luck next time &#128521;");

    } 
}

getMargaritas();

function theError(message = "Error") {
   return `<div class="error">${message}</div>`;
}

function makeNonBonkersResult(data){
    const fields = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    return data.drinks.map(d => {
      return {
         name: d.strDrink,
         ingredients: fields.filter(f => d["strIngredient" + f] != null)
                            .map(f => ({ingredient: d["strIngredient" + f], measure: d["strMeasure" + f]}))
      }
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="results"></div>
```